# Argon2 php vs Java hash_len

Tags: java, php, hash, argon

Is it possible to set the **Argon2** Hash length in PHP ?

updated question + answer on github: https://github.com/charlesportwoodii/php-argon2-ext/issues/9

Problem:
2 Apps communicating and doing encryption.
Now I want both apps to be able to create the same hash lengths.

The java app is using a hash_len of 24 while the php app has the default of 32.

The Java app is out of my control so how can I generate the same hash length in php ?

Those are the official php options:

> memory cost

> time cost

> threads

the standard php lib doesn't seem to support anything else, as far as I can see, any workarounds ?

in Java we can do something along those lines:

```
argon2.hash_password(
"Password",
memory_cost=512,
time_cost=2,
parallelism=2,
hash_len=24
)
```

In PHP

```
$options = [
"memory_cost" => 1024,
"time_cost" => 2,
"threads" => 2
];
password_hash('test', PASSWORD_ARGON2I, $options);
```

All I could think of as a workaround atm is maybe a python package which generates the hash with the length.

Python/PHP Example:

```
PHP
    $command = "python /path/to/argon2i_script.py 2>&1";
    $pid = popen( $command,"r");
    while( !feof( $pid ) )
    {
     echo fread($pid, 256);
     flush();
     ob_flush();
     usleep(100000);
    }
    pclose($pid);

Python
    import argon2, binascii
    
    hash = argon2.hash_password_raw(
        time_cost=16, memory_cost=2**15, parallelism=2, hash_len=32,
        password=b'password', salt=b'some salt', type=argon2.low_level.Type.ID)
    print("Argon2 raw hash:", binascii.hexlify(hash))
    
    argon2Hasher = argon2.PasswordHasher(
        time_cost=16, memory_cost=2**15, parallelism=2, hash_len=32, salt_len=16)
    hash = argon2Hasher.hash("password")
```

references:
[https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-08-17-php72-argon2-hash-password.html#:~:text=The%20hash%20size%20is%2032%20bytes.&text=The%20default%20parameters%20for%20the,2%20value%20for%20the%20memory_cost%20](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-08-17-php72-argon2-hash-password.html#:%7E:text=The%20hash%20size%20is%2032%20bytes.&text=The%20default%20parameters%20for%20the,2%20value%20for%20the%20memory_cost%20).
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-sodium-password-encoder